# How to show every change to an class object in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this skeleton of a game in two files.

First file `mygui.py`:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from mygame import p1, play_game

def rungame():
    play_game()
    gui_widgets()

root = Tk()

def gui_widgets():
    health_label = Label(root, text=f"health: {p1.health}")
    health_label.grid(column=0, row=0)

    mana_label = Label(root, text=f"mana: {p1.mana}")
    mana_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

    mybtn = Button(root, text="RUN GAME", command=rungame)
    mybtn.grid(column=0, row=2)

gui_widgets()
root.mainloop()
```

Seccond file `mygame`:

```
import time

class Player:

    def __init__(self, health, mana):
        self.health = health
        self.mana = mana

def play_game():
    p1.health -= 1
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p1.mana -= 3
    time.sleep(0.5)
    p1.mana += 1

p1 = Player(10, 15)
```

The game shows the begining statistic on gui and after clicking button it shows the end result. I want gui to show every `p1` atribute change made in `play_game()` as they are happening. How would I do this?

Edit: I am keen on keeping two seperate files so that program would be more scalable.

I am not sure if this is possible, but I would figure that if I could run `gui_widgets()` continuosly (for example every 0,1 secconds) It would probalby work as intended. Still I understand that this may be impossible since tkinter seems to wait everytime when `play_game()`is running, witch takes at least one seccond to finish. So in that case they should probalby run alongside each other (if that even is a thing).

Comment: It would be better as a single file.

Comment: @PCM This is minimal, reproducible example. The actual program has over 1000 lines of code sperated in three files. Previosly I have been using print statements to see what is happening, but since the complexity is groving it is more important to see what atributes have changed rather than endels lines of prints where looking for changes takes much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe lot of ways for it.

Here's one way

- Define `__setattr__` method to send signal to buffer to update GUI.
- `sleep` in main thread may block your GUI to update, so another thread used here.
- A fixed and short timer to fresh/update GUI from the content of buffer.

```py
# mygui.py
import threading
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button

from mygame import p1, play_game, buffer


def rungame():
    threading.Thread(target=play_game, args=(), daemon=True).start()

def update():

    if buffer:
        attribute, value = buffer.pop(0)
        if attribute == 'health':
            health_label.configure(text=f"health: {value}")
            health_label.update()
        elif attribute == 'mana':
            mana_label.configure(text=f'mana: {value}')
            mana_label.update()
    root.after(100, update)

def gui_widgets():

    health_label = Label(root, text=f"health:", width=20)
    health_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
    mana_label = Label(root, text=f"mana:", width=20)
    mana_label.grid(column=0, row=1)
    mybtn = Button(root, text="RUN GAME", command=rungame)
    mybtn.grid(column=0, row=2)
    return health_label, mana_label

root = Tk()

health_label, mana_label = gui_widgets()

root.after(100, update)
root.mainloop()
```

```py
#my game.py
import time

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, health, mana):
        self.health = health
        self.mana = mana

    def __setattr__(self, attribute, value):
        super().__setattr__(attribute, value)
        buffer.append((attribute, value))

def play_game():

    for i in range(10):
        p1.health = i
        time.sleep(0.2)
        p1.mana = 9 - i
        time.sleep(0.2)

buffer = []
p1 = Player(10, 15)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. While code you wrote works as requested I can't seem to find a way to make it work in two (or multiple) files. That would mean that I cant scale it up as I intend to do.

Comment: There's nothing different to split it into two scripts, update as above.